# Have a trouble to connect oracle database using by cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, pycharm, cx-oracle

I tried to connect oracle DB via PyCharm but I can't get through it yet. i did everything to fix this error but the error is still same. how to fix this error ?

error message -  "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/DBProject/exone.py", line 3, in 
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/orclpdb1")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help"

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWzYt.png)

Comment: The error means that you did not install the client libraries, as instructed by the link the error gave you. Or, if you installed them, you did not install the proper one, or the env configuration is wrong. You're using 32 bit system?

Comment: it is 64-bit version actually. I tried all of options in other solutions. But the result is same.

Comment: if it is an x64 system, then you probably installed a wrong version of some tool. It should not be asking for a 32bit library.

Answer (score 0):

Install 32-bit Oracle Instant Client and then change your script to call something like `init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_9")`, See the [cx_Oracle initialization doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory).